# LINUX How to get the non running PID-s?

Tags: linux, process, pid

I need a shell script to list all the non used(running) pid files.

How can I check if the pid isn't running?

Comment: get the pid from the file (file contents? file name?) then check the process list for that pid.

Comment: List all the .pid files in /var/run directory.I know that every .pid files contains a number which shows its process id.I have to compare it with all running processes.If the running processes doesn't contains that pid then I have to write that to the standard output.
The problem is that I can't compare all pids with all running processes.

Comment: `ps aux|grep '^$pid'`, basically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -d $'\0' -r f; do
  pid="$(cat "$f")"
  if ! ps "$pid" &> /dev/null; then
    echo "$pid"
  fi
done < <(find /run -type f -regextype posix-basic -regex '^.*\.pid$' -print0)
```